# How to properly store acids at home?

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry, safety

I bought different kinds of acid for experiments and home usage that I stored in secured containers into an IKEA cabinet.

I just realized that despite the fact that all the containers are properly closed, the metal parts of the cabinets are completely rotten. I am quite surprised because there shouldn't be much vapor in there.

What is the correct way to store acids at home? Should I purchase some specific container? How can I prevent vapors from escaping? Perhaps the problem is somewhere else and my containers are not good enough for my acids.

The acids I have: $\ce{H2SO4}$ (30%), $\ce{HCl}$ (32%), $\ce{H3PO4}$ (85%), $\ce{HNO3}$ (10%), $\ce{CH3COOH}$ (98%).

[image]
[image]

Note: the chemicals are actually stored in my electric/electronic workshop which is a separate room at home and always locked when I have visitors.

Comment: The correct way is _not_ to store acids at home.

Comment: Sorry about that, but you see yourself that an IKEA cabinet is not good enough.

Comment: @IvanNeretin well, so the solution is to buy something else like a chemical cabinet. Unfortunately these cabinets are also made of steel. So either I buy a hermetic cabinet or something else. I mean the problem would be the same if I want to store them in a workshop...

Comment: An proper acid cabinet isn't hermetically sealed. It is vented using an outside vent.

Comment: @MaxW I was afraid of this answer, but I can't afford this yet so I am looking for something else. What I am wondering is why do I have acid vapors since the bottles are all properly closed and made of thick plastic.

Comment: A "sealed" bottle contains liquid well. It does not contain gases well. There is also typically a bit of liquid left on the bottle threads after pouring some acid.

Comment: Unless your experiments require conc. HCl, you could store something about 10 ‰ and you should not see corrosion anymore, or at least just slow down the process. Among your list, problem is HCl 37 % with its fumes. You could also store the bottle you have in an almost sealed plastic box on the bottom of which you make a bed of baking soda, to be periodically renewed.

Comment: @dotancohen, the door wasn't closed

Comment: How long did it take to rust like that? Several years or just a few months or even weeks?

Comment: I would say several months.

Comment: @nowox several months sounds quite fast, but if it was a few years, than meh. In all 6 places storing acids I worked in, acid cabinet did rust somewhat heavily. Nobody really cared except to ensure reasonable ventilation. It takes too much effort to ensure sealing tight enouhg for it to be practical.

Comment: Salt water is enough to corrode some metals that bad. I once used metal tweezers to pick salt crystals from salt water solution and after a couple of weeks of just lying there they totally corroded.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

First I'd locate the bottle which causes the problem. Usually HCl is #1 suspect, but to be sure you can put a vial with smelling salts (aqueous solution of $\ce{(NH4)2CO3}$) or ammonia in the box with acids; white coating of $\ce{NH4Cl}$ on the bottle signifies the leak.

It's also a good practice to store acids in **glass** bottles with a proper joint (teflon ring) and a screw cap (e.g. Merck's SafetyCap). I would strongly recommend to get the proper bottles as soon as possible. Plastic bottles are only used to reduce the production and transportation costs, they are a poor choice for a long-term storing of chemicals. Even thick plastic is prone to diffusion, whereas glass is not; also plastic is, well, *plastic*, and is prone to mechanical deformations, so it's also tricky to maintain an impermeability of a bottleneck-cap joint over time.

In the meantime I'd wrap the necks of the bottles with [parafilm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parafilm), and/or pour some baking soda (sodium bicarbonate) on the bottom of the container where you store the bottles. This should help to neutralize the vapors before they reach the furniture and your nose, but it's a temporary solution.

Comment: Very good answer. I will try your smelling salts trick and look for ammonium chloride on the bottles. I am also suspecting the HCl. I will buy glass bottles with PTFE rings as well.

Comment: I'd check for chemical vendors in your vicinity, or maybe eBay or [LabX](http://www.labx.com/) (sometimes labs do sell equipment they don't need, so you might also get other stuff for the home lab for a reduced price, or even for free), and search specifically for the bottles to store acids with.

Comment: I am working in a research facility, I will ask some chemist there if they can help me with the purchase.

Comment: @nowox Oh, I forgot to mention that it's a good idea to get an **amber glass** bottle for $\ce{HNO3}$ as it's considerably light-sensitive. Other acids you listed are going to be fine in a regular glass bottles.

Comment: Glass works fine , except for HF.

Answer (score 0):

Do try to store these Acids in Glass containers..i have seen this in my school/college where they keep it inside glass cylinders.
Also glass containers being strong they hold the acids quite strongly and prevent any leakage to outside air.